# java jetty 9 connector configuration

Tags: java, connector, jetty-9

i'm using jetty 8 in my application and now i'm going to upgrade to jetty 9, but it seems that the connectors configuration is a little bit different, as in jetty 8, i used these code to configure the connector

```
server = new Server();
server.setThreadPool(threadPool);

SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();

connector.setHost(host);
connector.setPort(port);
connector.setMaxIdleTime(60000);
connector.setStatsOn(false);
connector.setLowResourcesConnections(20000);
connector.setLowResourcesMaxIdleTime(5000);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[]
{
    connector
});
```

now i need a equivalent code of this in jetty 9, but as far as i research, i can only found the following

```
    server = new Server(threadPool);

    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
    http_config.setOutputBufferSize(32768);

    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config));
    connector.setHost(host);
    connector.setPort(port);
    connector.setIdleTimeout(60000);
```

please anyone tell me that what happened to the setStatsOn, setLowResourcesConnections, and setLowResourcesMaxIdleTime??

thanks!